# In WebSphere Developer Tools (WDT) how do I open server log files in a different editor?

Tags: ibm-wdt

If I go to **Servers** view and right-click my server, then select *Open Log Files -> Current Message Log File* it always opens with the internal Eclipse Text Editor.

Is there a way to configure to open it with "System Editor"?

It seems like just using the **File Associations** preference isn't enough because somehow it is "locked" as a **Content Type** of *Runtime log files*.

Not sure where to go from here.

I realize there's a nice aspect to having Eclipse open it in avoiding open file handles, which can get in the way of deleting/renaming this file which happens as part of normal server operation.

But is this possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **File Associations** and create a content type of *.log.  You will notice this has a locked default text editor, but you can add another and make that the default.  Go to **Add...** at the bottom next to the **Associated editors**, click **External programs**, and pick the editor of your choice.  Then, click on this new entry under **Associated editors** and click **Default**.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'd tried something like that but got confused since it didn't take effect for log files that were already opened in an editor tab.   But that definitely works.